# Apache access log format does not record SSL_PROTOCOL for all connections

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, logging

We're trying to track the ssl protocol used by clients to our site/web services, the connections could be by browser, or, for the web services all sorts of soap libraries etc.
I've created a custom log format with ${SSL_PROTOCOL}e and ${SSL_CIPHER}e on our test server (see below)

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %m %H \" protocol:%{SSL_PROTOCOL}e:\" \"%{SSL_CIPHER}e\"" security
```

in apache2.conf and applied it successfully in available-sites

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log security
```

It works as expected for some traffic but not all, as far as I can see only php files that are POSTed to or GOT fill out the log correctly. Files downloaded as resources do not show the protocol or cipher mearly showing a `-` even though they seem to use ssl.

```
10.100.19.25:443 10.100.19.12 - - [16/Oct/2014:11:24:48 +0100] "GET /URL1/js/jsfile.js?_=1413454909537 HTTP/1.1" 200 5876 "https://testsite/URL1/URL2/File.php?token" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0" GET HTTP/1.1 "protocol:-:" "-"
```

Is there anyway of showing the ssl cipher used for all connections?